# MERGE Statment insert into from select pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle

How to create merge statment that insert into table from onther select statment

my example is :

```
    MERGE INTO employees t
        USING (SELECT :dept_id as dept_id FROM dual ) d
        ON (t.dept_id = d.dept_id )   
      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT INTO employees (
            ename,
            fname )
        SELECT
            ename,
            fname
        FROM
            trans_emps
        where trans_id = :trans_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO` with a `NOT EXISTS` filter:

```sql
INSERT INTO employees (ename, fname)
SELECT ename, fname
FROM   trans_emps
WHERE  trans_id = :trans_id
AND    NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM employees WHERE dept_id = :dept_id)
```

Or you can `MERGE` and move the `SELECT .. FROM trans_emps` into the `USING` clause:

```sql
MERGE INTO employees dst
USING (
  SELECT ename, fname
  FROM   trans_emps
  WHERE  trans_id = :trans_id
) src
ON (dst.dept_id = :dept_id)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( ename, fname )
  VALUES ( src.ename, src.fname );
```

Answer (score 1):

`merge` doesn't support such a syntax; `insert` clause can contain only `values` keyword (and list of values you're inserting into columns).

Switch to `insert` only (as your `merge` doesn't contain `when matched` clause anyway, so you aren't updating any rows in `employees`):

```
insert into employees (ename, fname)
select te.ename, 
       te.fname
from trans_emps te
where te.trans_id = :trans_id
  and exists (select null
              from employees a
              where a.dept_id = :dept_id
             );
```